# Testing for a bash Variable the right way

Tags: bash, dig

I have seen plenty of remarks on how to do this right, but somehow it does not work for me, and I am not sure why, some help would be appreciated.

Example Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -en "\ec"
echo "."
#Dig MX Record
    DIG="$(which dig --skip-alias)"
    CurrentDomain="example.com"
    echo -n "${CurrentDomain} MX "
    CurrentMX="$(${DIG} ${CurrentDomain} MX +short)"
    readarray -t  ArrMX <<< "$CurrentMX";
    if [[ -n ${ArrMX[@]} ]]
    then
        printf '%s\n' "${ArrMX[@]}"
    else
        echo "No Entry"
    fi
```

As you can see this is only part of a Program that loops over a list, most of the values work, but when dig returns nothing cause it has no MX entry, I get **MX: unbound variable** yet I do the -z test...

Any suggestions?

Comment: This code is working on my testbed :-? Which line is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your script you've set `set -u` which causes the shell to throw up errors when they are interpolated. As you've said in the case when `dig` fails, the `CurrentMX` variable is unset and when *trying* to access it in the `read` command to `MX` which is unset previously explicitly it throws the error.

Note that `dig` returns an empty result when it is not able to resolve a proper host. You could check that by just doing `/usr/bin/dig example.com MX +short` and compare it when you run with a proper host.

Also you seemed to have mixed-up the usage of arrays and variables in the `read` command, the `-a` flag of the `read` command takes in an array and *not* a variable.

Comment: @Inian I had _set -o nounset_ at the top of my script causing the problem. As for my Array usage, dig will return all MX entries with linefeeds, so it should be a array... I'll improve the code a bit however ;)